# Pre-fill forms + using privacy mode in Firefox in the same time

Tags: firefox

I have Scientific Linux 6.2 installed with Firefox.

I need to set Firefox that it doesn't saves the history/anything/etc, but it needs to save all the e-mail addresses that I typed in forms, ex.: facebook login, etc.

How can I do this? To pre-fill given forms and in the same time have "privacy mode" enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Privacy mode you could try turning off the features manually in `about:config`. I haven’t tried any of these but there are `places.history.enabled` and `browser.cache.disk.enable` settings.

Alternatively, how about using a password management addon? I use LastPass and a quick check shows it working in conjunction with Privacy Mode.